# Account setting for notifications of updates/changes to a Q/A

Tags: support, feature-request

Someone may reply to me without including an @mike.  A case in point is the Ridge Vent Q/A in which the OP replied to me: "The hot room is not vaulted. The entire attic has ventilation baffles. None of the soffits are blocked with insulation."

[Can too much ridge ventilation be detrimental?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32380/can-too-much-ridge-ventilation-be-detrimental#comment46475_32380)

In such cases, I have not been receiving notes or reminders in my inbox.

<s>I suppose 'favoriting' the question would have this effect</s>, though I'd rather  have the default behaviour to be to 'follow' any thread that I've participated in.  Is there an account setting to configure such a default?

Comment: There aren't any settings that I know of. In some situations you'll get notifications (comment on your post, comment immediately after your comment, etc) but otherwise they have to @ you for you to get the notification

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure if new SE users know to use @username.

Comment: Pretty sure most don't, unfortunately. I've missed my fair share of replies because of this.

Comment: I don't. And I was wondering why I didn't automatically received an email when someone posted to my question. I think that notification by email, if selected by the user, is much more user friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As best I know, there's no way to do this. You can follow the meta.SO request for this at [Mark questions to receive notifications and updates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates/52094#52094). Just don't get your hopes up that it will happen soon, that request was made back in 2009.